# looking for a regex pattern to remove contents in a JSON string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JSON string something similar to:

```
string str=[
   {"name": "Dukes",
    "lastname":"Chavez",
    "salary":"10000",
    "clearingbankAccinfo":"Westpac"}]
```

The issue is we have to clear the bank info, and that can be any value.
What we know for sure is it would come at the end of the string.

I need a regex pattern to remove this *clearingbankAccInfo* so that it looks something similar to:

```
string str=[
   {"name": "Dukes",
    "lastname":"Chavez",
    "salary":"10000"}]
```

Unfortunately I would have not accepted this as input itself but this information comes from a diff process and I have no control over what they pass.

I have tried:

```
String str=str.replace(',"clearingbankAccInfo":\g[a-zA-Z0-9_:]\g+', '' )
```

But it doesn't work correctly

Comment: Is it possible to parse the string as JSON, remove the key, and stringify it back to JSON? That way, your code would keep working even if the `clearingbankAccInfo` is no longer the last thing in the string.

Comment: sorry I did not get your answer. I already said I have no control over this and also I believe the json is stringifyed when sent to us for further processing.

Comment: You can match the part with `,?"clearingbankAccinfo":"\w+"` and then replace with an empty string. Using `\g` matches a `g` char, which is not there. If you meant to use the global flag `str=str.replace(/,?"clearingbankAccinfo":"\w+"/g, '');`

Comment: You're processing the string in javascript, so you can do this: `let obj = JSON.parse(str)` to turn it into a javascript object, then delete the key, then stringify again with `let newStr = JSON.stringify(obj)`

Comment: you mean String newString=str.replace(/,?"clearingbankAccinfo":""\w+"/g,'' ); this does work... i have tried this. many thanks

Comment: Many have suggested it's better to use `JSON.parse` to convert the string to object first.  Although you are sure `clearingbankAccinfo` would come at the end of string, the JSON format does not guarantee the order of fields, also the fields could be separated by new lines.  At later time you might have more fields added to the string and break the assumption that clearingbankAccinfo is the last field.  The process could also change and outputs json with new lines.  You could fix the problem using regex now, but it's very likely the program will break in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with something like JSON regex is the wrong solution. Simply [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) the stringified data, and loop over it with something like [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract and return the correct data. Then you can just make a [string again out of that data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```js
const str = '[{"name": "Dukes","lastname": "Chavez","salary": "10000","clearingbankAccinfo": "Westpac"},{"name": "Bob","lastname": "Smith","salary": "20000","clearingbankAccinfo":"Lloyds"}]';

// Here we're creating a new variable called `newData` to hold
// the transformed data. We parse the data string and iterate over it
// (because it's now an array) with `map` which is an array method.
// With each iteration we take the object, grab the clearingBankAccinfo
// and just return everything else.
const newData = JSON.parse(str).map(obj => {
  const { clearingbankAccinfo, ...rest } = obj;
  return rest;
});

console.log(newData);
console.log(JSON.stringify(newData));
```

Additional documentation

- [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)
- [Working with JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: What's wrong with the `delete` keyword? Why is the map necessary? What's wrong with parse, delete, stringify -- 3 simple lines of code? Note: this isn't a criticism, I'm genuinely wondering what I'm missing here.

Comment: This is javascript

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer there's nothing wrong with `delete`. It mutates the data rather than returning a new array. But if you want to offer that up as a solution please go ahead.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer FWIW I didn't see it as a criticism. Your solution is correct. Sometimes finding the balance on this site is halfway between _telling_ someone (who is perhaps new to coding) how to do something, and _teaching_ them how they might approach a solution. It's why I make a decent attempt to litter my code with comments, and pointers to documentation that they might useful in the future. It's the bane, and a pleasure, of being senior engineer to junior ones.

Comment: My issue is resolved thanks to fourthbird

Comment: Fair enough. Just remember in future that using regex to fix something is not often the best course of action in JavaScript, particularly when there are lots of wonderful ways to manipulate data. You had an array; just use all of the great array methods that are available to you.

Comment: @dukechavez ... your problem is not solved. It just appears to you like it is/was. What others already mentioned more nicely can be said bluntly ... you just unnecessarily introduced a point of a not that unlikely future failure with this unthoughtful regex based patch despite off much more reliable approaches which were offered to you.

Answer (score -3):

str=str.replace(/,?"clearingbankAccinfo":"\w+"/g, '');

Comment: That's not a solution, it's a really poor hack.